# MinGW undefined reference to `___atomic_fetch_sub_4'

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw, atomic, compare-and-swap

When trying to build a simple test program that uses atomic operations, I get the error 
`` undefined reference to `___atomic_fetch_sub_4' ``
Specifically, it only happens when I do a `--` combined with `==`:

```
std::atomic<std::size_t> foo;
if (--foo == 42) { ... }
```

The code compiles fine, but I get the error while trying to link. I'm using MinGW with GCC 4.7.

Comment: According to [this bug ticket](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=102435&aid=3420359&group_id=2435), MinGW for x86 does not yet support atomics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::thread` and `std::atomic` still have very limited support with MinGW. If you want to experiment with those C++11 features on windows, I recommend [Visual Studio 2012 RC](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us).

Comment: The problem is Visual Studio 2012RC still doesn't have the variadic templates I need

Comment: Well, the only option then would be to use [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) which has support for atomics (however, I cannot guarantee that you won't run into any problems). Also, `std::thread` and `std::regex` are still lacking.